# MYSQL doesn't return first row

Tags: php, mysql

```
$Day = mysqli_real_escape_string($Connection, $_GET['day']); //1
$Str = "-".$Day." day"; //"-1 day"
$MinRange = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Str))." 00:00:00"; //2013-12-07 00:00:00
$MaxRange = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Str))." 23:59:59"; //2013-12-07 23:59:59
$query = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT * FROM `counter` WHERE time BETWEEN '{$MinRange}' AND '{$MaxRange}'") or die (mysqli_error($Connection));

while($Counter = mysqli_fetch_array($query))  
{  
echo $Counter['id'];  
}
```

It always skip the first row but it still doesn't works when I don't use ranges, might be the looping problem? I seen people use this loop without problems

Comment: Use placeholders. The problem is probably with the information in the database or limits supplied (such that it's not "between" the values). Also, for just checking a date, compare as `WHERE DATE(x) = ..` (no need to deal with the time). In any case, an ORDER BY *must* be present to get reliable record order.

Comment: Looks like it's not the loop problem nor the query problem since SELECT * FROM `counter` didn't even work, so now I'm guessing it's MySQLi problem? I had no problem with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If your code works except for the first row, you either need to start your search the day before at 23:59:59 or also try adding a LIMIT 0, 30 the second number can be whatever you want it to be, See if that works.

Comment: My search is searching before 23:59:59 and limit isn't working. The first row is 15:52:04

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer, and my guess is you've some kind of ID which is the primary key:

```
"SELECT * FROM `counter` WHERE time BETWEEN '{$MinRange}' AND '{$MaxRange} ORDER BY `id` DESC"
```

This would return ONE value, which would be the latest record.

Comment: I need multiple returns

Comment: Not sure why your code was bugging out - give the update a go. ^^